# How to hash std::string_view?

Tags: c++, hash, c++17, string-view

I am trying to define my own hashing function for `std::unordered_map` and I want to hash a field within a struct which is supposed to be the key. The code below is a simplified version of what I have:

```
struct TestStruct {
    char a[64];
    char b[64];
}

struct my_eq {
    bool operator()(const TestStruct& test_1, const TestStruct& test_2) const {
        return !strcmp(test_1.a, test_2.a) && !strcmp(test_1.b, test_2.b);
    }
};

struct my_hash {
    unsigned long operator()(const TestStruct& test) const {
        return std::hash<std::string_view>(std::string_view(test.a));
    }
};
std::unordered_map<TestStruct, int, my_hash,my_eq> map;
```

The error I get is:

```
no matching function for call to ‘std::hash<std::basic_string_view<char> >::hash(std::string_view&)
```

According to the [cppreference on `std::hash`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) the hash function should support `std::string_view`.  I feel like I'm missing something simple but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Are you sure you are compiling C++17? I imagine C++14 is still the default for many compilers.

Comment: @patatahooligan  `-std=c++1z` is the current compiler flag.

Comment: @Galik great catch. that would have resulted in an annoying bug. I'll update my post with the suggested fixes (excluding the hash fix ofc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using `std::hash` wrong.  `std::hash` is a class which provides a `operator()` that hashes the object.  You are trying to pass the object to its constructor which doesn't work since it only has a default consdtructor.  Your `operator()` also needs to be marked `const`.  We put that all together and we get:

```
struct my_hash {
    unsigned long operator()(const TestStruct& test) const {
        return std::hash<std::string_view>()(std::string_view(test.a));
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

`std::hash` is a class template, **not** a function template. you need an instance to call it:

```
return std::hash<std::string_view>()(std::string_view(test.a));
```